# not able to connect to a Samba server from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, samba

I tried all the day to connect to my Samba server on Raspbian from a Windows 7 laptop.

First, I've a Windows 7 **Home Edition** after reading some article it seems it's important to note as I'm wondering if it is even possible to use that edition with Samba. Note also, that on this Windows 7, I've a Debian VM that is able to connect to Samba, hehe.

I already read a lot of articles and solutions, so I think its not trivial and deserves a question here but I'm also new to Samba and I probably miss something stupid.

### Samba conf file

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
dns proxy = no
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
syslog = 0
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
server role = standalone server
passdb backend = tdbsam
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
pam password change = yes
map to guest = bad user
usershare allow guests = yes

[homes]
comment = Home Directories
browseable = no
read only = yes
create mask = 0700
directory mask = 0700
valid users = %S

[printers]
comment = All Printers
browseable = no
path = /var/spool/samba
printable = yes
guest ok = no
read only = yes
create mask = 0700

[print$]
comment = Printer Drivers
path = /var/lib/samba/printers
browseable = yes
read only = yes
guest ok = no



[share]
Comment = Pi shared folder
Path = /home/pi/sync_images
Browseable = yes
Writeable = Yes
only guest = no
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
Public = yes
Guest ok = yes

[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
netbios name = LINUXSERVER
lanman auth = no
ntlm auth = yes
client lanman auth = no
wins support = yes
local master = yes
preferred master = yes
```

### Samba user profil

```
$ sudo pdbedit -L -v

Unix username:        pi
NT username:          
Account Flags:        [U          ]
User SID:             S-1-5-21-940656554-1247367340-895234526-1000
Primary Group SID:    S-1-5-21-940656554-1247367340-895234526-513
Full Name:            
Home Directory:       \\linuxserver\pi
HomeDir Drive:        
Logon Script:         
Profile Path:         \\linuxserver\pi\profile
Domain:               RASPBERRYPI
Account desc:         
Workstations:         
Munged dial:          
Logon time:           0
Logoff time:          never
Kickoff time:         never
Password last set:    ven., 04 mai 2018 17:53:14 CEST
Password can change:  ven., 04 mai 2018 17:53:14 CEST
Password must change: never
Last bad password   : 0
Bad password count  : 0
Logon hours         : FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

### Tests I did to connect from my Win 7

```
net use X: \\RASPBERRYPI\share /USER:pi *********              *no hit*
net use X: \\LINUXSERVER\share /USER:pi *********              *no hit*
net use X: \\linuxserver\share /USER:pi *********              *no hit*
net use X: \\RASPBERRYPI\share /USER:WORKGROUP\pi *********    *no hit*
net use X: \\LINUXSERVER\share /USER:WORKGROUP\pi *********    *no hit*
net use X: \\linuxserver\share /USER:WORKGROUP\pi *********    *no hit*
```

each time, I get the 53 error.

### `regedit` modifications

I also Tried old `regedit` solutions about Windows 7 and Samba found here and there. Basically it was : 
create a DWORD key

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa/LmCompatibilityLevel
```

set it to 2. reboot, doesn't worked.

change `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\everyoneincludesanonymous` from 0 to 1

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\NoLmHash` from 1 to 0
 `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters\restrictnullsessaccess` 1 to 0

Rebooot, not hit

### Questions

Any idea of what I can do ?  Also do you know if an alternative to Windows Samba Client exists and can be installed ? my goal is to use Python to sync some folders on my Raspberry Pi to Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to sync folders between your PI and Windows, you can install an SCP server like OpenSSH for Windows (free) or Bitvise SSH Server (may be non-free; not sure) on your Windows system and copy the files from your Linux box (your PI) using common SCP commands at your Linux box invoked from Python.

Comment: I will give it a try. What I do now is using SFTP, was simpler.

Comment: @snoobdogg great!, SCP and SFTP are like cousins :) both take care transferring the files using secure protocols.  Good look!